# Finding white space in string and replace that with another in an array

Tags: javascript

I have a set of strings in array like `['1254','1556',' 515']`. From here I want to look for a string which has a white space and three digits. Also I want to replace that string with `----`. How can I do that as the strings are in an array?

Comment: You should iterate that array and solve the problem for the string you find there? What is the problem? Can you share your code so we can help you out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could take a regular expression for testing the string and replace the value for a new array.

```js
var array = ['1254','1556',' 515'],
    result = array.map(s => /^\s\d{3}$/.test(s) ? '----' : s);

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
^(?=.* )(?=.*\d{3})[\d\s]+$
```

[image]

```js
let arr = ['1254','1556',' 515']

let replaceStr = (str) => {
  return str.replace(/^(?=.* )(?=.*\d{3})[\d\s]+$/,(match)=> '-'.repeat(match.length))
}

let final = arr.map(replaceStr)

console.log(final)
```